How does an atomic<shared_ptr<>> work internally?
How does an atomic<shared_ptr<>> work internally ? I'm not asking for the mechanics of the control block alongside with the stored data, which is easy to imagine for me, but for the atomic<shared_ptr<>> itself.
For VC++ the code for the atomic store is that:
void store(shared_ptr<_Ty> _Value, const memory_order _Order = memory_order_seq_cst) noexcept {
    _Check_store_memory_order(_Order);
    const auto _Rep                  = this->_Repptr._Lock_and_load();
    remove_extent_t<_Ty>* const _Tmp = _Value._Ptr;
    _Value._Ptr                      = this->_Ptr.load(memory_order_relaxed);
    this->_Ptr.store(_Tmp, memory_order_relaxed);
    this->_Repptr._Store_and_unlock(_Value._Rep);
    _Value._Rep = _Rep;
}

But this doesn't help me much.

It seems to me that it takes a lock, loads a value from the other pointer, stores it using this pointer, and then unlocks the lock. So "atomic" but apparently not lock free. The interface allows, but cannot require the operation to be lock free on all hardware.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a10JpqI-CvU might be of interest

It's unrolling the swap part of copy-swap idiom. _Repptr in the atomic has a locking mechanism in control block.

Note that they can be implemented with _InterlockedCompareExchange128/cmpxchg16b (but I'm not sure if anyone currently does so)

@user541686: MSVC, libstdc++ and libc++ currently report atomic<shared_ptr>::is_lock_free() with zero.

@EdisonvonMyosotis: Right, I believe there's a comment in MSVC's implementation indicating they plan to do that in the future.

@user541686: I guess that if all major implementations report atomic<shared_ptr> not to be lock-free it's impossible.

@EdisonvonMyosotis: No, it might mean they have other considerations to worry about (like ABI stability, bandwidth, etc.)

@user541686: "Bandwidth" with a shared_ptr<> ??? And the ABI would be the same.

@EdisonvonMyosotis: I meant bandwidth to do the work. Maybe there's no ABI impact, I haven't checked to see how they work internally. Regardless, I'm not here to argue with you, I'm just telling you it's in no way impossible, and "if it hasn't been done then it must HN be because it's impossible" is silly logic. You can insist on whatever you want though.

@EdisonvonMyosotis An alternate hypothesis is that not enough of the customers of those implementations are asking for lock-free atomic<shared_ptr<X>> for it to be a development priority.

@Caleth: Runtime libraries should use the most efficient solution since the designer can't make assumptions on their usage.

I did it myself and implemented an thread-safe "shared_ptr" with DW-CAS.
I'm using split reference counting, having a counter in the second DW-CAS word which counts the number of increments in the control-block which will proceed soon. So there's no difference to other implementations. The problem with other implementations is that after the counter beside the pointer is incremented the whole pointer may be overwritten multiple times and at last the pointer-part will be the same like before, but the counter might have a value from other threads which are about to increment the counter in the control block. So the first incrementer might become scheduled away and get back after the same pointer is re-established with an update-counter from other threads. That is the point where other implementations fail.
So my solution is was to make this counter only 32 bit wide and use the upper 32 bits as a sequence counter which is incremented if the pointer is overwritten. So when the control block's counter is updated and the threads comes back to decrement the update-counter beside the pointer it can see if the update-counter is the one which the thread has updated before or not.
This is my code:
#pragma once
#include <atomic>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>
#include <new>
#include "dcas_atomic.h"
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    #include <intrin.h>
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
    #include <x86intrin.h>
#endif

template<typename T>
struct shared_obj;

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
shared_obj<T> make_shared_obj( Args &&... args );
template<typename T>
struct tshared_obj;

template<typename T>
struct shared_obj
{
    shared_obj() noexcept;
    shared_obj( shared_obj && ) noexcept;
    shared_obj( shared_obj const & ) noexcept;
    shared_obj( tshared_obj<T> const & ) noexcept;
    shared_obj( tshared_obj<T> && ) noexcept;
    shared_obj &operator =( shared_obj && ) noexcept;
    shared_obj &operator =( shared_obj const & ) noexcept;
    shared_obj &operator =( tshared_obj<T> const & ) noexcept;
    shared_obj &operator =( tshared_obj<T> && ) noexcept;
    ~shared_obj();
    T *get() const noexcept;
    operator bool() const noexcept;
    size_t use_count() const noexcept;
    T &operator *() const noexcept;
    T *operator ->() const noexcept;
    void reset() noexcept;
private:
    template<typename T2, typename ... Args>
    friend shared_obj<T2> make_shared_obj( Args &&... args );
    template<typename T2>
    friend struct tshared_obj;
    struct ctrl_t
    {
        template<typename ... Args>
        ctrl_t( Args &&... args );
        T m_obj;
        std::atomic<size_t> m_refCount;
    };
    shared_obj( ctrl_t *obj );
    ctrl_t *m_ctrl;
};

template<typename T>
inline shared_obj<T>::shared_obj() noexcept :
    m_ctrl( nullptr )
{
}

template<typename T>
inline shared_obj<T>::shared_obj( shared_obj &&other ) noexcept :
    m_ctrl( other.m_ctrl )
{
    other.m_ctrl = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
inline shared_obj<T>::shared_obj( shared_obj const &other ) noexcept :
    m_ctrl( other.m_ctrl )
{
    size_t before = m_ctrl->m_refCount.fetch_add( 1, std::memory_order_relaxed );
    assert(before != (size_t)-1);
}

template<typename T>
template<typename ... Args>
inline shared_obj<T>::ctrl_t::ctrl_t( Args &&... args ) :
    m_obj( std::forward<Args>( args ) ... ),
    m_refCount( 1 )
{
}

template<typename T>
shared_obj<T> &shared_obj<T>::operator =( shared_obj &&other ) noexcept
{
    // both pointed to objects are equal ?
    if( m_ctrl == other.m_ctrl ) [[unlikely]]
    {
        // remove reference from other
        other.m_ctrl = nullptr;
        size_t before = m_ctrl->m_refCount.fetch_sub( 1, std::memory_order_relaxed );
        assert(before > 1);
        return *this;
    }
    // delete before object if necessary
    if( m_ctrl && m_ctrl->m_refCount.fetch_sub( 1, std::memory_order_release ) == 1 )
        delete m_ctrl;
    // move object ponter
    m_ctrl = other.m_ctrl;
    other.m_ctrl = nullptr;
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
shared_obj<T> &shared_obj<T>::operator =( shared_obj const &other ) noexcept
{
    // our and other pointer are equal ?
    if( m_ctrl != other.m_ctrl ) [[likely]]
    {
        // no: quit with our current object
        this->~shared_obj();
        // copy other's object
        new( (void *)this ) shared_obj<T>( other.m_ctrl );
        m_ctrl->fetch_add( 1, std::memory_order_acquire );
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
shared_obj<T>::~shared_obj()
{
    // we have a managed object and we're the only one pointing to it ?
    if( m_ctrl && m_ctrl->m_refCount.fetch_sub( 1, std::memory_order_release ) == 1 )
        // yes: delete the object
        delete m_ctrl;
}

template<typename T>
inline T *shared_obj<T>::get() const noexcept
{
    return &m_ctrl->m_obj;
}

template<typename T>
inline shared_obj<T>::operator bool() const noexcept
{
    return (bool)m_ctrl;
}

template<typename T>
inline size_t shared_obj<T>::use_count() const noexcept
{
    // we've a managed object ?
    if( m_ctrl ) [[likely]]
        // yes: return its use count
        return m_ctrl->m_refCount.load( std::memory_order_relaxed );
    // no: use-count is zero
    return 0;
}

template<typename T>
inline shared_obj<T>::shared_obj( ctrl_t *obj ) :
    m_ctrl( obj )
{
}

template<typename T>
inline T &shared_obj<T>::operator *() const noexcept
{
    assert(m_ctrl);
    return m_ctrl->m_obj;
}

template<typename T>
inline T *shared_obj<T>::operator ->() const noexcept
{
    return &m_ctrl->m_obj;
}

template<typename T>
inline void shared_obj<T>::reset() noexcept
{
    this->~shared_obj();
    new( (void *)this ) shared_obj<T>( nullptr );
}

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
shared_obj<T> make_shared_obj( Args &&... args )
{
    return shared_obj<T>( new shared_obj<T>::ctrl_t( std::forward<Args>( args ) ... ) );
}

template<typename T>
struct tshared_obj
{
    tshared_obj() noexcept;
    tshared_obj( shared_obj<T> const & ) noexcept;
    tshared_obj( shared_obj<T> && ) noexcept;
    ~tshared_obj();
    tshared_obj &operator =( shared_obj<T> const & ) noexcept;
    tshared_obj &operator =( shared_obj<T> && ) noexcept;
    void reset() noexcept;
private:
    template<typename T2>
    friend struct shared_obj;
    using ctrl_t = shared_obj<T>::ctrl_t;
    using pair_t = dcas_atomic::pair_t;
    static constexpr unsigned
        SZT_BITS = sizeof(size_t) * 8,
        UPDATER_BITS = SZT_BITS / 2,
        SEQENCE_BITS = SZT_BITS / 2;
    static constexpr size_t
        UPDATER_VALUE = 1,
        SEQUENCE_VALUE = (size_t)1 << UPDATER_BITS,
        UPDATER_MASK = SEQUENCE_VALUE - 1,
        SEQUENCE_MASK = ~UPDATER_MASK;
    mutable dcas_atomic m_dca;
    ctrl_t *copy() const noexcept;
    ctrl_t *remove() noexcept;
    void store( ctrl_t *obj ) noexcept;
};

template<typename T>
shared_obj<T>::shared_obj( tshared_obj<T> const &ts ) noexcept :
    m_ctrl( ts.copy() )
{
}

template<typename T>
shared_obj<T>::shared_obj( tshared_obj<T> &&ts ) noexcept :
    m_ctrl( ts.remove() )
{
}

template<typename T>
shared_obj<T> &shared_obj<T>::operator =( tshared_obj<T> const &ts ) noexcept
{
    using namespace std;
    // important optimization for RCU-like patterns:
    // we're managing the same object like the thread-safe object-pointer ?
    if( (size_t)m_ctrl == ts.m_dca.first().load( memory_order_relaxed ) ) [[likely]]
        // yes: nothing to do
        return *this;
    // erase our object pointer
    this->~shared_obj();
    // copy() increments the reference count for ourself
    new( (void *)this ) shared_obj<T>( ts.copy() );
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
shared_obj<T> &shared_obj<T>::operator =( tshared_obj<T> &&ts ) noexcept
{
    // erase our object pointer
    this->~shared_obj();
    // move ts' object-pointer
    new( (void *)this ) shared_obj<T>( ts.remove() );
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
inline tshared_obj<T>::tshared_obj() noexcept :
    m_dca( pair_t( 0, 0 ) )
{
}

template<typename T>
tshared_obj<T>::~tshared_obj()
{
    // pointer to managed object
    ctrl_t *obj = (ctrl_t *)m_dca.first().load( std::memory_order_relaxed );
    // no managed object ?
    if( !obj )
        // yes: nothing to do
        return;
    // there must be no current updaters
    assert(!(m_dca.second() & UPDATER_MASK));
    // decrement reference count of managed object
    size_t before = obj->m_refCount.fetch_sub( 1, std::memory_order_release );
    assert(before > 0);
    // we're the only one pointing to the managed object ?
    if( before == 1 )
        // yes: delete the object
        delete obj;
}

template<typename T>
inline tshared_obj<T>::tshared_obj( shared_obj<T> const &so ) noexcept :
    m_dca( pair_t( (size_t)so.m_ctrl, 0 ) )
{
    // increment so's reference count
    size_t before = so.m_ctrl->m_refCount.fetch_add( 1, std::memory_order_release );
    assert(before > 0 && before != (size_t)-1);
}

template<typename T>
inline tshared_obj<T>::tshared_obj( shared_obj<T> &&so ) noexcept :
    m_dca( pair_t( (size_t)so.m_ctrl, 0 ) )
{
    so.m_ctrl = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
tshared_obj<T> &tshared_obj<T>::operator =( shared_obj<T> const &so ) noexcept
{
    // pointer to so's object
    ctrl_t *obj = so.m_ctrl;
    // we're pointing to the same object ?
    if( (size_t)obj == m_dca.first().load( std::memory_order_relaxed ) )
        // yes: nothing to do
        return *this;
    // increment reference count
    size_t before = obj->m_refCount.fetch_add( 1, std::memory_order_relaxed );
    assert(before && before != (size_t)-1);
    // store object pointer, maybe deallocate old
    store( obj );
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
tshared_obj<T> &tshared_obj<T>::operator =( shared_obj<T> &&so ) noexcept
{
    // move so's object pointer
    ctrl_t *obj = so.m_ctrl;
    so.m_ctrl = nullptr;
    // store object pointer, maybe deallocate old
    store( obj );
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
inline void tshared_obj<T>::reset() noexcept
{
    using namespace std;
    // remove object pointer
    ctrl_t *obj = remove();
    // there was no object ?
    if( !obj ) [[unlikely]]
        // yes: nothing further to do
        return;
    // decrement reference count
    size_t before = obj->m_refCount.fetch_sub( 1, memory_order_relaxed );
    assert(before > 0);
    // we were the only pointing to obj ?
    if( before == 1 ) [[unlikely]]
        // yes: delete the object
        delete obj;
}

// Copies the content of an atomic shared object to a pointer.
// Proceeds in three steps:
// 1. Increment the update counter.
// 2. Increment the reference counter
// 3. Decrement the update counter if pointer and sequence counter hasn't changed.
// Reference counter has been incremented for the next sharer

template<typename T>
typename tshared_obj<T>::ctrl_t *tshared_obj<T>::copy() const noexcept
{
    using namespace std;
    // increment updater value of our DCAS'd pointer
    pair_t expected( m_dca.first().load( memory_order_relaxed ), m_dca.second().load( memory_order_relaxed ) ), desired;
    do [[unlikely]]
        // there's a managed object ?
        if( expected.first ) [[likely]]
            // yes: desired is the same except for one more updater
            desired = { expected.first, expected.second + UPDATER_VALUE };
        else
            // no: nothing to do, return no managed object
            return nullptr;
    while( !m_dca.compare_exchange( expected, desired, dcas_relaxed() ) );
    // pointer to managed object
    ctrl_t *obj = (ctrl_t *)desired.first;
    // increment reference count
    size_t rcBefore = obj->m_refCount.fetch_add( 1, memory_order_acquire );
    assert(rcBefore != (size_t)-1);
    size_t
        // remember managed pointer, it must be the same with the next CMPXCHG 
        ptr = desired.first,
        // remember managed sequence counter, it must be the same with the next CMPXCHG 
        seq = desired.second >> UPDATER_BITS;
    // expect that we've still the last set DCAS-atomic
    expected = desired;
    // make desirecd.second to decrement the updater-counter
    auto updateCtr = [&]
    {
        assert((expected.second & UPDATER_MASK) >= UPDATER_VALUE);
        desired.second = expected.second - UPDATER_VALUE;
    };
    updateCtr();
    // decrement updater counter failed ?
    while( !m_dca.compare_exchange( expected, desired, dcas_relaxed() ) ) [[unlikely]]
        // yes: pointer and sequence-counter still the same ?
        if( expected.first == ptr && expected.second >> UPDATER_BITS == seq ) [[likely]]
            // yes: update updater's count
            updateCtr();
        else
            // no: new managed object, nothing more to do
            break;
    return obj;
}

// Removes the atomic pointer, preparing it to be moved.
// Reference-count remains.

template<typename T>
inline typename tshared_obj<T>::ctrl_t *tshared_obj<T>::remove() noexcept
{
    using namespace std;
    pair_t expected( m_dca.first().load( memory_order_relaxed ), m_dca.second().load( memory_order_relaxed ) ), desired;
    desired.first = 0;
    do [[unlikely]]
    {
        if( !expected.first ) [[unlikely]]
            return nullptr;
        desired.second = expected.second + SEQUENCE_VALUE & SEQUENCE_MASK;
    } while( !m_dca.compare_exchange( expected, desired, dcas_relaxed() ) );
    return (ctrl_t *)expected.first;
}

// Replaces the atomic pointer and deletes the old if there aren't pending loads.
// Reference count of new object must have been already at least one.
// New object's reference should be set to at least one before.
// If old object's reference count drops to zero object is destroyed.

template<typename T>
inline void tshared_obj<T>::store( ctrl_t *obj ) noexcept
{
    using namespace std;
    pair_t
        // set the expected value to the current state of the DCA (maybe split and not consistent)
        expected( m_dca.first().load( memory_order_relaxed ), m_dca.second().load( memory_order_relaxed ) ),
        // the desired object pointer should be "obj"
        desired( (size_t)obj, 0 );
    // set new object pointer and counters
    do
        // failed: we're still pointing to a different object than "obj" ?
        if( expected.first != desired.first ) [[likely]]
            // no: set new sequence counter to the current plus one and no updaters
            desired.second = expected.second + SEQUENCE_VALUE & SEQUENCE_MASK;
        else
        {
            // one reference count too much since we're moving obj into our state
            size_t before = obj->m_refCount.fetch_sub( 1, memory_order_relaxed );
            assert(before > 1);
            return;
        }
    while( !m_dca.compare_exchange( expected, desired, dcas_release() ) );
    // pointer to object before
    ctrl_t *oldObj = (ctrl_t *)expected.first;
    // empty: nothing to delete
    if( !oldObj ) [[unlikely]]
        return;
    // decrement reference counter of before object
    size_t before = oldObj->m_refCount.fetch_sub( 1, std::memory_order_relaxed );
    assert(before);
    // last reference count and there were no current updaters ?
    if( before == 1 && !(desired.second & UPDATER_MASK) ) [[unlikely]]
        // yes: delete object
        delete oldObj;
}

This is the DW-CAS header dcas_atomic.h:
#pragma once#pragma once
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>
#include <atomic>
#include <type_traits>
#include <climits>
#include <bit>
#include <memory>

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    #pragma warning(push)
    #pragma warning(disable: 26495)
#endif
#if defined(__llvm__)
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Watomic-alignment"
#endif

constexpr int
    DCAS_ACQ_REL = (int)std::memory_order::acq_rel,
    DCAS_ACQUIRE = (int)std::memory_order::acquire,
    DCAS_RELAXED = (int)std::memory_order::relaxed,
    DCAS_RELEASE = (int)std::memory_order::release,
    DCAS_SEQ_CST = (int)std::memory_order::seq_cst;
template<int Type>
using dcas_type = std::integral_constant<int, Type>;
using dcas_acq_rel = dcas_type<DCAS_ACQ_REL>;
using dcas_acquire = dcas_type<DCAS_ACQUIRE>;
using dcas_relaxed = dcas_type<DCAS_RELAXED>;
using dcas_release = dcas_type<DCAS_RELEASE>;
using dcas_seq_cst = dcas_type<DCAS_SEQ_CST>;

struct dcas_atomic
{
    static_assert(sizeof(size_t) == 8 || sizeof(size_t) == 4, "must be 64 or 32 bit architecture");
    struct pair_t { size_t first, second; };
    dcas_atomic() = default;
    dcas_atomic( pair_t const &desired );
    std::atomic<size_t> &first() noexcept;
    std::atomic<size_t> &second() noexcept;
    operator pair_t() noexcept;
    template<int Type>
    bool compare_exchange( pair_t &expected, pair_t const &desired, dcas_type<Type> = dcas_seq_cst() ) noexcept;
    template<int Type>
    pair_t load( dcas_type<Type> = dcas_seq_cst() ) const noexcept;
    template<int Type>
    void store( pair_t const &niu, dcas_type<Type> = dcas_seq_cst() ) noexcept;
private:
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) && !defined(_MSC_VER)
    #if SIZE_WIDTH == 64
    using dword_t = unsigned __int128;
    #elif SIZE_WIDTH == 32
    using dword_t = unsigned long long;
    #else
        #error unknown architecture
    #endif
#endif
    union alignas(2 * sizeof(size_t)) U
    {
        U() {}
        static_assert(sizeof(std::atomic<size_t>) == sizeof(size_t), "sizeof(atomic<size_t>) must be == sizeof(size_t)");
        std::atomic<size_t> m_atomics[2];
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    #if defined(_M_X64) || defined(_M_ARM64) || defined(_M_ARM64EC)
        __int64 volatile m_firstAndSecond[2];
    #elif defined(_M_IX86)
        __int64 volatile m_firstAndSecond;
    #else
        #error unknown architecture
    #endif
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
        dword_t volatile m_firstAndSecond;
#endif
    } u;
};

inline dcas_atomic::dcas_atomic( pair_t const &desired )
{
    u.m_atomics[0].store( desired.first, std::memory_order_relaxed );
    u.m_atomics[1].store( desired.second, std::memory_order_relaxed );
}

inline std::atomic<size_t> &dcas_atomic::first() noexcept
{
    return u.m_atomics[0];
}

inline std::atomic<size_t> &dcas_atomic::second() noexcept
{
    return u.m_atomics[1];
}

inline dcas_atomic::operator pair_t() noexcept
{
    return pair_t( first().load( std::memory_order_relaxed ), second().load( std::memory_order_relaxed ) );
}

template<int Type>
inline bool dcas_atomic::compare_exchange( pair_t &expected, pair_t const &desired, dcas_type<Type> ) noexcept
{
    using namespace std;
    static_assert(Type == DCAS_ACQ_REL || Type == DCAS_ACQUIRE || Type == DCAS_RELAXED || Type == DCAS_RELEASE || Type == DCAS_SEQ_CST);
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    #if defined(_M_X64) || defined(_M_ARM64) || defined(_M_ARM64EC)
    __int64 expectedA[2];
    expectedA[0] = (__int64)expected.first;
    expectedA[1] = (__int64)expected.second;
    char fRet;
    #if defined(_M_X64)
    fRet = _InterlockedCompareExchange128( u.m_firstAndSecond, desired.second, desired.first, expectedA );
    #else
    if constexpr( Type == DCAS_ACQ_REL || Type == DCAS_SEQ_CST )
        fRet = _InterlockedCompareExchange128( u.m_firstAndSecond, desired.second, desired.first, expectedA );
    else if constexpr( Type == DCAS_ACQUIRE )
        fRet = _InterlockedCompareExchange128_acq( u.m_firstAndSecond, desired.second, desired.first, expectedA );
    else if constexpr( Type == DCAS_RELAXED )
        fRet = _InterlockedCompareExchange128_nf( u.m_firstAndSecond, desired.second, desired.first, expectedA );
    else
        fRet = _InterlockedCompareExchange128_rel( u.m_firstAndSecond, desired.second, desired.first, expectedA );
    #endif
    if( fRet )
        return true;
    expected.first = expectedA[0];
    expected.second = expectedA[1];
    return false;
    #elif defined(_M_IX86)
    auto compose = []( pair_t const &p ) -> uint64_t { return p.first | (uint64_t)p.second << 32; };
    uint64_t
        cDesired = compose( desired ),
        cExpected = compose( expected ),
        cResult = _InterlockedCompareExchange64( &u.m_firstAndSecond, cDesired, cExpected );
    if( cResult == cExpected ) [[likely]]
        return true;
    expected.first = (uint32_t)cResult;
    expected.second = (uint32_t)(cResult >> 32);
    return false;
    #else
        #error unspupported Windows-platform
    #endif
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
    constexpr auto
        pair_t::*FIRST = std::endian::native == std::endian::little ? &pair_t::first : &pair_t::second,
        pair_t::*SECOND = std::endian::native == std::endian::little ? &pair_t::second : &pair_t::first;
    auto compose = []( pair_t const &p ) -> dword_t { return (dword_t)(p.*FIRST) | (dword_t)(p.*SECOND) << SIZE_WIDTH; };
    dword_t
        dwExpected = compose( expected ),
        dwDesired = compose( desired );
    bool ret;
    if constexpr( Type == DCAS_ACQ_REL )
        ret = __atomic_compare_exchange_n( &u.m_firstAndSecond, &dwExpected, dwDesired, true, __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL, __ATOMIC_RELAXED );
    else if constexpr( Type == DCAS_ACQUIRE )
        ret = __atomic_compare_exchange_n( &u.m_firstAndSecond, &dwExpected, dwDesired, true, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE, __ATOMIC_RELAXED );
    else if constexpr( Type == DCAS_RELAXED )
        ret = __atomic_compare_exchange_n( &u.m_firstAndSecond, &dwExpected, dwDesired, true, __ATOMIC_RELAXED, __ATOMIC_RELAXED );
    else if constexpr( Type == DCAS_RELEASE )
        ret = __atomic_compare_exchange_n( &u.m_firstAndSecond, &dwExpected, dwDesired, true, __ATOMIC_RELEASE, __ATOMIC_RELAXED );
    else
        ret = __atomic_compare_exchange_n( &u.m_firstAndSecond, &dwExpected, dwDesired, true, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST, __ATOMIC_RELAXED );
    if( ret ) [[likely]]
        return true;
    expected.*FIRST = (size_t)dwExpected;
    expected.*SECOND = (size_t)(dwExpected >> SIZE_WIDTH);
    return false;
#else
    #error unspupported platform
#endif
}

template<int Type>
inline typename dcas_atomic::pair_t dcas_atomic::load( dcas_type<Type> ) const noexcept
{
    using namespace std;
    static_assert(Type == DCAS_ACQ_REL || Type == DCAS_ACQUIRE || Type == DCAS_RELAXED || Type == DCAS_RELEASE || Type == DCAS_SEQ_CST);
    pair_t cmp( 0, 0 );
    const_cast<dcas_atomic *>(this)->compare_exchange( cmp, cmp, dcas_type<Type>() );
    return cmp;
}

template<int Type>
inline void dcas_atomic::store( pair_t const &niu, dcas_type<Type> ) noexcept
{
    using namespace std;
    static_assert(Type == DCAS_ACQ_REL || Type == DCAS_ACQUIRE || Type == DCAS_RELAXED || Type == DCAS_RELEASE || Type == DCAS_SEQ_CST);
    pair_t cmp( *this );
    while( !this->compare_exchange( cmp, niu, dcas_type<Type>() ) );
}

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    #pragma warning(pop)
#endif
#if defined(__llvm__)
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
#endif

The solution is slightly faster than the futex'd solution from MSVC and multiple times faster than the current libstdc++- and libc++-solution.

Out of curiosity, what's the rationale for disabling C26495 for MSVC and -Watomic-alignment for clang in your DW-CAS implementation? Specifically, what triggers them and why are the things they diagnose not important?

@Erel: Without that I'd get a warning that DWCAS'es are slow, although that's not true. It's not really the time to do the DWCAS, but to fetch the cacheline from a remote cache.

A naive implementation is to hash the address of the atomic<shared_ptr<T>> object and use the hash as an index into an array of mutexes. So when you need to access the shared_ptr object, the corresponding mutex is locked. If two threads need to access different atomic<shared_ptr<T>> objects, then most of the time they'll hash to different slots so there won't be contention.
Lock-free implementations are difficult. You can find discussion here.

Not necessary. A futex takes just a byte and you can initialize it with one instruction.

@EdisonvonMyosotis a futex does not provide a lock-free implementation. It's  possible that a futex may preferable over an array of mutexes implementation. But notice that adding a futex will increase the size of the class and may be dead weight if the binary is run on a system that doesn't support futexes.

It wasn't me who suggested a mutex. And if there are futexes better use them instead of a mutex.

@EdisonvonMyosotis I think you ignored the part of my comment that explains the potential downside of adding a futex to every object of the class.

A futex can be just a byte. And because you've got the space to the aligment it has a size of a size_t, that's eight bytes, nearly not noteworthy.

@EdisonvonMyosotis It's your assumption that increasing the size of a class from 16 to 24 would not be important for anyone just because it's not important for you.

Your suggestion isn't better either because you need a poiner to the pooled mutex.

@EdisonvonMyosotis No, the address of the atomic itself is hashed and used to determine the index into the mutex array. And the mutex array itself is a global variable.

A lot of complexity to save 8 bytes ...
